# submiting game with .blend files

Tags: unity-game-engine, publish, blend, leap-motion, fbx

I have an unity project with blender objects saved in .blend files. I wasn't able to export them as fbx becouse everything it totally messed them up when I tried this. However I found that .blend files can be imported to unity also. Now, when I finished my project I want to submit it to the leap motion store but I'm afraid the .blend files won't let it work becouse when I runned the project in another computer from unity, it required blender installed on the compute, which won't happen on clients' computers. Is it possible to leave .blend files in the project or I have to export them in any case to spesific format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a project from inside the unity editor and running the project as a compiled game are totally different things. You don't need blender installed to run the compiled game.